# Turn off the highlight feature in the Limp

Tags: vim, lisp, common-lisp

I am using the Limp in my VIM. But there is a problem, when the cursor move to a "(" or ")", it would highlight a block of code in this pair.I can not see the code clearly. Is there any way to turn off or delete this feature?

Best Regards,

Comment: Just to make sure: "highlight a block of code in this pair" - does Limp highlight the matching parenthesis, or does it actually highlight all the code between the two parens? The first is a standard vim plugin which can be disabled easily. The second would be a specific feature of Limp.

Comment: It highlight all the code between the two parens. I want to keep the Limp, juts want to turn off the highlight feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also using Limp but I have modified it somewhat to work better for my tastes.

Inside the main limp folder there is a `vim` subfolder, open the file `limp.vim` and at the end you can see several `runtime` commands, just comment out the one that loads the `highlight.vim` file:

```
"runtime ftplugin/lisp/limp/highlight.vim
```

I also like to disable the `autoclose.vim` plugin, I find it very annoying.

```
"runtime ftplugin/lisp/limp/autoclose.vim
```

Then, open the file `mode.vim` and around line number 58 you can see the function call to initialize the highlighting mode; comment it out:

```
"call LimpHighlight_start()
```

then around line number 68, under the function `LimpMode_stop()` you will also need to comment the call to stop the highlightning.

```
"call LimpHighlight_stop()
```

Of course, if you also disabled the `autoclose.vim` plugin you'll also have to comment the calls to start/stop it.

#### Annoying colors

If the colors that Limp sets up out of the box annoys you as they did with me, you can disable that and continue using your default colorscheme; around line number 30:

```
"set t_Co=256
"if !exists("g:colors_name")
    "colorscheme desertEx
"endif
```

And change the highlight groups to match your colorscheme (use :high to quickly see a list of color combinations). For example, I use the *"desertEx"* colorscheme and changed this two lines to match it:

```
hi BracketsBlock ctermbg=235 guibg=grey22
hi StatusLine    ctermbg=black ctermfg=160
```

#### Other options

I didn't like the set of options that Limp sets, especially the old Vi Lisp indentation. I also dislike the folding so I disabled that too. My current set of options look like this:

```
syntax on
setlocal nocompatible nocursorline
setlocal lisp syntax=lisp
setlocal ls=2 bs=2 et sw=2 ts=2 "tw=0 
setlocal statusline=%<%f\ \(%{LimpBridge_connection_status()}\)\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
"setlocal iskeyword=&,*,+,45,/,48-57,:,<,=,>,@,A-Z,a-z,_
"setlocal cpoptions=-mp
"setlocal foldmethod=marker foldmarker=(,) foldminlines=1
setlocal foldcolumn=0

set lispwords+=defgeneric,block,catch,with-gensyms

"-----------
"Taken from the bundled lisp.vim file in VIM
"(/usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/lisp.vim)
setl comments=:;
setl define=^\\s*(def\\k*
setl formatoptions-=t
setl iskeyword+=+,-,*,/,%,<,=,>,:,$,?,!,@-@,94
setl comments^=:;;;,:;;,sr:#\|,mb:\|,ex:\|#
setl formatoptions+=croql
"-----------

" This allows gf and :find to work. Fix path to your needs
setlocal suffixesadd=.lisp,.cl path+=/home/gajon/Lisp/**
```

Notice I disabled the `tw=0`, modified the `statusline`, disabled folding, copied the options that come bundled with Vim (they are a lot better), added some symbols to `lispwords`, and added a missing dot to `suffixesadd` (cl extension was missing a dot).

#### Disabling the transposing of sexps.

Limp binds they keys <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> to functions that transpose the current sexp with the previous/next sexp. But they don't work reliably and I think they are unnecessary when you can just as easily use <kbd>dab</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> at the proper place. Besides the default Vim <kbd>{}</kbd> bindings are quite useful to move to other top-level forms.

In file `keys.vim`:

```
"nmap <buffer> {                    <Plug>SexpMoveBack
"nmap <buffer> }                    <Plug>SexpMoveForward
```

#### Bug when connecting to a running REPL

There's a bug that prevents Limp from reconnecting to an already running REPL. In file `bridge.vim` inside the `vim` subfolder, around line number 13:

```
let cmd = s:Limp_location . "/bin/lisp.sh ".core_opt." -s ".styfile." -b ".name
```

A space was missing between `".core_opt."` and `-s`.

#### Additional Goodies!

You should be able to figure out how to use these new mappings.

In file `bridge.vim` add the following lines after line number 265:

```
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>EvalUndefine   :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(fmakunbound '".expand("<cword>").")")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>EvalAddWord    :let &lispwords.=',' . expand("<cword>")<cr>

nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>DebugTrace         :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(trace ".expand("<cword>").")")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>DebugUnTrace       :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(untrace ".expand("<cword>").")")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>DebugInspectObject :call LimpBridge_inspect_expression()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>DebugInspectLast   :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(inspect *)")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>DebugDisassemble   :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(disassemble #'".expand("<cword>").")")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>DebugMacroExpand   :call LimpBridge_macroexpand_current_form( "macroexpand" )<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>DebugMacroExpand1  :call LimpBridge_macroexpand_current_form( "macroexpand-1" )<CR>

nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>ProfileSet      :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(sb-profile:profile ".expand("<cword>").")")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>ProfileUnSet    :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(sb-profile:unprofile ".expand("<cword>").")")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>ProfileShow     :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(sb-profile:profile)")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>ProfileUnSetAll :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(sb-profile:unprofile)")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>ProfileReport   :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(sb-profile:report)")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>ProfileReset    :call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp("(sb-profile:reset)")<CR>
```

And at the end add these two functions:

```
function! LimpBridge_inspect_expression()
  let whatwhat = input("Inspect: ")
  call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp( "(inspect " . whatwhat . ")" )
endfun

function! LimpBridge_macroexpand_current_form(command)
  " save position
  let pos = LimpBridge_get_pos()

  " find & yank current s-exp
  normal! [(
  let sexp = LimpBridge_yank( "%" )
  call LimpBridge_send_to_lisp( "(" . a:command . " '" . sexp . ")" )
  call LimpBridge_goto_pos( pos )
endfunction
```

Then in file `keys.vim` add the following mappings:

```
" Undefine: Undefine a function or macro.
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>eu      <Plug>EvalUndefine

" Add Word: Append word to 'lispwords' option
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>ea      <Plug>EvalAddWord

" Trace: Set tracing for function.
" Untrace: Remove tracing for a function.
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>dt      <Plug>DebugTrace
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>du      <Plug>DebugUnTrace

" Inspect: Inspect object
" InspectPrev: Inspect last value evaled.
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>di      <Plug>DebugInspectObject
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>dI      <Plug>DebugInspectLast

" Disassemble:
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>dd      <Plug>DebugDisassemble

" Macroexpand:
" Macroexpand1:
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>ma      <Plug>DebugMacroExpand
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>m1      <Plug>DebugMacroExpand1

" Profile: Set profiling.
" Unprofile: Remove profiling.
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>pr      <Plug>ProfileSet
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>pu      <Plug>ProfileUnSet

" Show Profiling: Show profiling.
" Unprofile All: Remove all profiling.
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>pp      <Plug>ProfileShow
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>pa      <Plug>ProfileUnSetAll

" Profile Report: Show report.
" Profile Reset: Reset profile data.
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>ps      <Plug>ProfileReport
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>p-      <Plug>ProfileReset

" Sexp Close Open Parenthesis:
nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>cp      <Plug>SexpCloseParenthesis
imap <buffer> <C-X>0               <C-O><LocalLeader>cp
```

Then in file `sexp.vim` add this mapping:

```
" Sexp Close Open Parenthesis:
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Plug>SexpCloseParenthesis  :call SlimvCloseForm()<CR>
```

and these two functions:

```
"-------------------------------------------------------------------
" Close open parenthesis
" Taken from the Slimv plugin by Tamas Kovacs. Released in the
" public domain by the original author.
"-------------------------------------------------------------------

" Count the opening and closing parens or brackets to determine if they match
function! s:GetParenCount( lines )
    let paren = 0
    let inside_string = 0
    let i = 0
    while i < len( a:lines )
        let inside_comment = 0
        let j = 0
        while j < len( a:lines[i] )
            if inside_string
                " We are inside a string, skip parens, wait for closing '"'
                if a:lines[i][j] == '"'
                    let inside_string = 0
                endif
            elseif inside_comment
                " We are inside a comment, skip parens, wait for end of line
            else
                " We are outside of strings and comments, now we shall count parens
                if a:lines[i][j] == '"'
                    let inside_string = 1
                endif
                if a:lines[i][j] == ';'
                    let inside_comment = 1
                endif
                if a:lines[i][j] == '(' || a:lines[i][j] == '['
                    let paren = paren + 1
                endif
                if a:lines[i][j] == ')' || a:lines[i][j] == ']'
                    let paren = paren - 1
                    if paren < 0
                        " Oops, too many closing parens in the middle
                        return paren
                    endif
                endif
            endif
            let j = j + 1
        endwhile
        let i = i + 1
    endwhile
    return paren
endfunction

" Close current top level form by adding the missing parens
function! SlimvCloseForm()
    let l2 = line( '.' )
    normal 99[(
    let l1 = line( '.' )
    let form = []
    let l = l1
    while l <= l2
        call add( form, getline( l ) )
        let l = l + 1
    endwhile
    let paren = s:GetParenCount( form )
    if paren > 0
        " Add missing parens
        let lastline = getline( l2 )
        while paren > 0
            let lastline = lastline . ')'
            let paren = paren - 1
        endwhile
        call setline( l2, lastline )
    endif
    normal %
endfunction
```

Hope this helps you better use Limp.

Comment: Thanks very much. The information you provide is very very useful